# schema2ddl generates wrong datatype for YesNoType

Tags: hibernate

As per docs org.hibernate.type.YesNoType is supposed to generate char(1) during schema2ddl generation. But the following definition generates char(255) by default for databases like H2, MySQL

```
@Column(name = "enabled")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.YesNoType")
private Boolean enabled = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Adding a hardcoded value for columnDefinition as "char(1)" does create the SQL properly.
What am I missing here, is there any workaround to solve this issue without using columnDefinition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Column` annotation defaults length to 255; hence the behavior you're seeing.

Removing it won't help either, actually, because implicit column definition created by Hibernate's `AnnotationBinder` iin the absence of explicit `@Column` / `@Columns` also defaults to 255 :-)

You need to [explicitly specify column length](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property-column) but the good news is you don't have to do that via `columnDefinition`:

```
@Column(name = "enabled", length = 1)
```